# How to use gzip or gunzip in a pipeline with curl (For binary gz files)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, gzip, gunzip

I am using curl to download a file using the following command.

```
curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz
```

I want to unpack it in a pipeline in the following way.
curl -O url | unpack it and store it here in current directory

I used the following command, however, it does not work. I get`"gzip: stdin: not in gzip format"` Any ideas how can I achieve this?

```
curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz | gunzip
```

I simply want to achieve something like this:

```
download somecompressedfile | decompress it.
```

or as simple as this:

```
ls | grep test.gz | decrompess test.gz
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
curl -o - https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz | gunzip > ./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin
```

**Explanation:**
`-` represents the standard output. The standard output is what gets redirected by piping with `|`.
From [man curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> Specifying the output as '-' (a single dash) will force the output to be done to stdout.

Comment: Can you tell me what the - does after -o? seems like that does trick?

Comment: Somehow the above didn't work for me, I had to use this `-L` as well `curl -L -o - <URL> | gunzip > <file_name>`